# geom_bar in ggplot - add a break / gap between two bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a bar chart in R where there is a gap between two groups of bars, (but not a grouped bar chart). I have data here with each of 30 basketball teams and their average points:

```
dput(mydf)
structure(list(thisTeamAbb = c("ATL", "BKN", "BOS", "CHA", "CHI", 
"CLE", "DAL", "DEN", "DET", "GSW", "HOU", "IND", "LAC", "LAL", 
"MEM", "MIA", "MIL", "MIN", "NOP", "NYK", "OKC", "ORL", "PHI", 
"PHX", "POR", "SAC", "SAS", "TOR", "UTA", "WAS"), pts = c(1.197, 
1.138, 1.016, 1.127, 1.196, 1.144, 1.21, 1.197, 1.155, 1.107, 
1.126, 1.138, 1.282, 1.105, 1.096, 1.205, 1.121, 1.125, 1.205, 
1.208, 1.208, 1.098, 1.056, 1.167, 1.039, 1.128, 0.99, 1.171, 
0.987, 1.127)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

> head(mydf)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  thisTeamAbb   pts
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 ATL          1.20
2 BKN          1.14
3 BOS          1.02
4 CHA          1.13
5 CHI          1.20
6 CLE          1.14
```

and with it i am able to make this plot with 30 bars, with the bars sorted increasingly:

```
mydf %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(thisTeamAbb, pts), y = pts), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

...however this graph has too many bars.

Instead, I'd like to simply graph the 5 bars with the lowest values, and 5 bars with the highest values, with a 'gap' between the two sets of bars that indicates that the other 20 bars belong in the middle but have been taken out.

I'm not quite sure if geom_bar has a way to handle this, or if i need to edit my dataframe. Any help with this is appreciated!!

Comment: There are good arguments against discontinuous axes, omitting data can be misleading. As it's bars which make the plot look crowded, how about points instead? Try this (requires libraries ggrepel and dplyr) and see what you think: `mydf %>% mutate(q = ntile(pts, 6)) %>% ggplot(aes(q, pts)) + geom_point() + geom_text_repel(aes(label = thisTeamAbb, color = factor(q))) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:6) + guides(color = FALSE) + theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank()) + scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

my_df2 %>%
  mutate(rank = <-
  bind_rows(
    my_df %>% top_n(wt = pts, 5),
    my_df %>% slice(1) %>% mutate(thisTeamAbb = "Middle 20", pts = NA_real_),
    my_df %>% top_n(wt = pts, -5)  # Includes 6 b/c ties....
) %>%
# Here I make the team name into sorted factor, with Middle 20 in the middle
mutate(thisTeamAbb = thisTeamAbb %>% 
           fct_reorder(pts) %>%
           fct_relevel("Middle 20", after = 5))

my_df2 %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = thisTeamAbb, y = pts), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about making use `facet_wrap`?

```
df %>%
    mutate(region = case_when(
        min_rank(desc(pts)) <= 5 ~ "high",
        min_rank(pts) <= 5 ~ "low",
        TRUE ~ "middle")) %>%
    filter(region %in% c("low", "high")) %>%
    mutate(
        thisTeamAbb = reorder(thisTeamAbb, pts),
        region = factor(region, c("low", "high"))) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(thisTeamAbb, pts)) +
    facet_wrap(~ region, scale = "free_x") +
    theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))
```

[image]

You can adjust the gap between panels via `panel.spacing` inside `theme`.

---

### Update

With a bit of extra "theme-ing"

```
df %>%
    mutate(region = case_when(
        min_rank(desc(pts)) <= 5 ~ "high",
        min_rank(pts) <= 5 ~ "low",
        TRUE ~ "middle")) %>%
    filter(region %in% c("low", "high")) %>%
    mutate(
        thisTeamAbb = reorder(thisTeamAbb, pts),
        region = factor(region, c("low", "high"))) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(thisTeamAbb, pts)) +
    facet_wrap(~ region, scale = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        panel.spacing = unit(5, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Comment: i would prefer avoiding the facet wrap for the same reasons i am avoiding the grouped bar chart, which is mainly for aesthetics. i think a simple gap looks much nicer (and i can add annotations in the blank space)

Comment: @Canovice Fair enough. I think the facets have some advantages (like being able to label the strips which avoids having to fiddle with additional annotations) and they just look tidier. But that's obviously my subjective opinion;-) PS. I've updated the plot slightly to make it cleaner.